# Limit YouTube to Wi-Fi only

Tags: wi-fi, youtube, data-monitoring

My daughter loves to share videos on YouTube with her friends. As a result she's blown through her monthly 2GB data allotment on multiple occasions.

While I've educated her on the difference between 3G and Wi-Fi, and she's a smart kid, it would simply be easier if I could limit her YouTube app to only allow streaming while on Wi-Fi.

I looked in the app settings but unless it's in some weird location there is no such setting. How can I prevent YouTube streaming to be only allowed on Wi-Fi?

(If it matters: Droid Incredible 2, Gingerbread)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know of any YouTube option for that end, but if you are open to use an app to limit other apps, you can give a go to [Onavo Count | Monitor Data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid) that has an option to limit the app to Wi-Fi only:

> Save money on your mobile bill - avoid costly overage fees! Onavo Count puts you in control of your 3G data plan. Easy setup, three brand new widgets, tailored alerts and automatic blocking tools will keep you safe from bloated data bills.

**Update September 2016**:
It looks like Onavo Count is no longer compatible with some modern Android devices including devices like Nexus 6P. Onavo has a new "Protect Free VPN+Data Manager", which still has the above functionality in addition to some cool VPN features.

[image: Onavo Limit to Wi-Fi Only]

Comment: I installed this app, and I can't see YouTube in the list of apps (at 'details'). Am I doing something wrong? I did start up the app to make sure it at least used some data so that it should appear in the list.

Answer (score 3):

[avast! Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) has, in addition to multiple layers of protection, a firewall module that allows individual control of each application with toggling of Wi-Fi/data/roaming access.

Onavo also works great as mentioned but doesn't have the other features that Avast has.

Comment: You can only use avast firewall if you have root access on your android

Answer (score -1):

No Root Firewall can restrict cellular access on per app basis

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall