# Which service provides Facebook notifications and how to disable it to use mobile network

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-nexus, facebook, data-connection

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to disable services from using mobile data connection on my Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean.

I've disabled Facebook to use mobile data connection, but I'm still getting Facebook notifications<sup>1</sup> which is very odd. I'd like to disable it on mobile network completely and only have it enabled while on wifi.

My main mobile data connection users are:

1. **Google Services** - is it possible to control individual ones because there are many within this one and I can't even see which ones because they're all truncated
2. **Gmail** - I want this one enabled on Wifi *and* mobile network
3. **Facebook** (?!?!?!) - should be disabled on mobile
4. **Google Search** - what do I lose if I disable this one as well? which app uses this one? I'm not using Google Now on mobile network anyway.
5. ...

I don't want to resort to manually disabling/enabling Facebook app every time I go to work which would hopefully disable these notifications as well.

> **1:** Those notifications that display Facebook icon in notification area, not those that get delivered to my Gmail and I'd actually get email notifications about emails related to Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing an app firewall such as [DroidWall](http://code.google.com/p/droidwall/) (needs root) and disallow 3G access for the Facebook app.

Comment: [Onavo Count](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid) helps manage 3G data usage and doesn't require root.

Comment: I'm not interested in rooting... :(

Comment: @AlEverett: But ICS/JB already have great data monitoring tool built into the system that also includes setting margins etc. That's actually the tool that I used to get this data from initially anyway. What additional stuff does Onavo give me on top of that if anything at all?

Comment: Ah, yes. Forgot about that. I'm not sure. I do know that my daughter's Gingerbread phone had nothing like that, so I installed Onavo on hers. There are some blocking mechanisms in Onavo that might help. ([A related question I asked](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28947/limit-youtube-to-wi-fi-only))

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can control the data connection for your Facebook notifications. You can have notifications on or off.

You might consider increasing your notification interval to reduce the impact of the notifications. (I see no need to receive Fbook notifications every 30 minutes.)

There *may* be a Tasker (et al.) "recipe" which can turn on/off Facebook notifications based on location, existence of wi-fi, etc., but I don't have any knowledge there.