# How to make an app only work on wifi (never use data even if opened)

Tags: wi-fi, data-monitoring

I have a new Android version 5.1, Moto E 2nd Gen.

I just figured out which apps used up all my cell data, so I want to make it so these data-guzzling apps (the ones I want to keep) work ONLY on wifi, even if accidentally opened - Like turning off data but for only specific apps. Is this possible?

1. I already disabled the background data, updates, and sync - this doesn't get rid of ALL data usage though.
2. I tried this post: [Limit apps to only work if connected to WiFi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/limit-apps-to-only-work-if-connected-to-wifi) But this is a different system or something from the one I'm using, the answer does not work on my phone exactly as shown. If something similar works for mine, please give me step by step of how to do it with mine.

Thank you!

Comment: The best way to do it requires an app but it works best if rooted. Are you rooted?

Comment: You need a firewall application